# How do I update columns in a table by joining it with 5 other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to update a table which has only two fields
test_set_id and plan_id 
which i can get easily from this query

```
SELECT      tp.plan_id
        ,   r.release_id
FROM        test_plan tp
        ,   releases r
        ,   test_run tr
        ,   iteration i
WHERE       tr.iteration_id = i.iteration_id
AND         i.release_id    = r.release_id
AND         tr.plan_id      = tp.plan_id
AND         i.release_id    = 1
GROUP BY    plan_id
```

but when I run the following query, it is giving me an sql error.

```
UPDATE  test_set_relation
SET     test_set_id
    ,   plan_id=
        (   SELECT      tp.plan_id
                    ,   r.release_id
            FROM        test_plan tp
                    ,   releases r
                    ,   test_run tr
                    ,   iteration i
            WHERE       tr.iteration_id = i.iteration_id
            AND         i.release_id    = r.release_id
            AND         tr.plan_id      = tp.plan_id
            AND         i.release_id    = 1
            GROUP BY    plan_id
        )
```

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: You have two columns in your `SET` clause:  `SET test_set_id,plan_id` Which should it be?

Comment: Which row/rows do you want to update in `test_set_relation`?  What is the relationship between the row you intend to update and your `select`?

Comment: Also: do you want to update one row or many?

Comment: Implicit join syntax is a very poor technique that can cause accicdental cross joins and maintainability issues and was replaced 20 years ago with explicit syntax. Why are you still using it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign multiple field values like that in SET.

```
SET test_set_id,plan_id=(SELECT tp.plan_id,r.release_id
```

This will throw the error `Incorrect syntax near ','.` *(this error message is from SQL Server)* because the query is expected to have an assignment operator **=** next to the column name.

Your query should be formulated something along this line. Without knowing how your tables are structured, it is not possible to formulate a valid *UPDATE* statement.

*Usage*: *`SQL Server` syntax*

```
UPDATE      t1
SET         t1.col2 = t2.col2
        ,   t1.col3 = t2.col3
FROM        table1 t1
INNER JOIN  table2 t2
ON          t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

*Usage*: *`MySQL` syntax*

```
UPDATE      table t1
JOIN
SET         t1.col2 = t2.col2
        ,   t1.col3 = t2.col3
INNER JOIN  table2 t2
ON          t1.col1 = t2.col1
```